# ImportError: cannot import name dump_publickey

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, urllib3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Successfully installed `pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python` , but i'm unable to print snowflake version. Don't know what could be the issue. Followed steps provided in below link.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#step-2-verify-your-installation

```
import snowflake.connector

    # Gets the version
    ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user='<your_user_name>',
        password='<your_password>',
        account='<your_account_name>'
        )
    cs = ctx.cursor()
    try:
        cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
        one_row = cs.fetchone()
        print(one_row[0])
    finally:
        cs.close()
    ctx.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "validate.py", line 7, in <module>
    account='abc123'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/__init__.py", line 32, in Connect
    return SnowflakeConnection(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 147, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 355, in connect
    self.__open_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 548, in __open_connection
    self.__authenticate(auth_instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 771, in __authenticate
    session_parameters=self._session_parameters,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth.py", line 214, in authenticate
    socket_timeout=self._rest._connection.login_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 529, in _post_request
    _include_retry_params=_include_retry_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 618, in fetch
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 695, in _request_exec_wrapper
    raise e
ImportError: cannot import name dump_publickey
```

Can anyone help me please ?

**LOGS:**

```
INFO:snowflake.connector.connection:Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 1.6.11, Python Version: 2.7.14, Platform: Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.connection:connect
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.connection:__config
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.converter:use_sfbinaryformat: False, use_numpy: False
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.connection:REST API object was created: account_name.snowflakecomputing.com:443, proxy=None:None, proxy_user=None
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.auth:authenticate
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.auth:assertion content: *********
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.auth:account=account_name, user=user_name, database=None, schema=None, warehouse=None, role=None, request_id=29f36950-7763-4cee-ab48-bbe3716ca916
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.auth:body['data']: {u'CLIENT_APP_VERSION': u'1.6.11', u'CLIENT_APP_ID': u'PythonConnector', u'CLIENT_ENVIRONMENT': {u'PYTHON_VERSION': u'2.7.14', u'APPLICATION': u'PythonConnector', u'OS_VERSION': 'Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit', u'PYTHON_COMPILER': 'GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)', u'OS': 'Darwin', u'PYTHON_RUNTIME': 'CPython'}, u'ACCOUNT_NAME': 'account_name', u'SVN_REVISION': None, u'LOGIN_NAME': 'user_name'}
DEBUG:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry:Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
DEBUG:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry:Converted retries value: 1 -> Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.network:Active requests sessions: 1, idle: 0
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.network:remaining request timeout: 120, retry cnt: 1
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.network:socket timeout: 60
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): account_name.snowflakecomputing.com
DEBUG:snowflake.connector.network:Active requests sessions: 0, idle: 1
```

After debugging `network.py`, could make out that in  `def _request_exec` ,  executing url `https://account_name.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=9b1c563d-80a2-4608-af4d-8bc6b955ac70&request_guid=b88aba49-384a-409d-8387-4e4f934927ab` in below block encounters error

```
raw_ret = session.request(
                method=method,
                url=full_url,
                proxies=proxies,
                headers=headers,
                data=input_data,
                timeout=socket_timeout,
                verify=True,
                stream=is_raw_binary,
                auth=SnowflakeAuth(token),
            )
```

Could be issue with any modules related to api/url-execution (`requests,urllib3`), just a guess. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Tried and tired of re-installing with sudo -H as well. don't know what could be the issue. can anyone help please  ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code out and it works fine for me. Have you tried to enable logging? If yes can you share the logs? Also make sure you've got the account details right.

Just in case you don't have logging enabled it can be enabled by adding the following lines to your python script:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/tmp/snowflake_python_connector.log',
    level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @harshc. unable to post logs here, updating in question section.

Comment: any module problems on my MAC ?

Comment: account details are right and when i execute the same script on my friend's machine, it works fine. Not sure what could be wrong here.

Comment: could able to import snowflake.connector successfully, really can't make out what could be wrong here.

Comment: I doubt it's a problem with requests/urllib3 but for your own sake you can quickly test it out on python command line using examples [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Also from your original question I am guessing you're killing a stuck application. Can you try waiting for the application to kill itself due to timeout? Is there a chance the logs are truncated because of a Ctrl+C? The session.request call has a default time out of DEFAULT_SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT which is 60 sec, so you should wait at least for that long.

Comment: Another thing which would be interesting to know would be the output of `pip list`

Comment: i have tried and detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095452/unable-to-connect-to-snowflake-python , please check and let me know if any more information required.

Comment: pip-list/site-packages have been listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095452/unable-to-connect-to-snowflake

Comment: In pip list I was expecting to see Cryptography, PyOpenSSL.  I checked the packages on my Mac and it has the above two, in addition it has pycryptodomex and asn1crypto too. I don't see Cryptography and asn1crypto in your list. Both of these packages are used by the python connector.

Comment: i have installed all of them, it's mentioned in two screenshots attached here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095452/unable-to-connect-to-snowflake

Comment: any specific version dependent ?

Comment: any idea ? 
do you need any more info ?

Comment: Well I just noticed your pyOpenSSL version - it's 0.13.x , that's **really** old. Snowflake did not exist back then and I am pretty sure versions that old are not supported .. :D Try updating it to the latest18.0.0