# How do i enforce to use a single python path to be used?

Tags: python

I could see multiple python paths available on mac.

```
import sys
 sys.path

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Users/rshastri/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-3.8.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py-1.6.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy-0.7.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pathlib2-2.3.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/more_itertools-4.3.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/attrs-18.2.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atomicwrites-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scandir-1.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.12-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scandir-1.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.12-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scandir-1.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.12-x86_64.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Lasagne-0.2.dev1-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.13.1-py2.7-macosx-10.5-intel.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-intel.egg
/Users/rshastri/Downloads/snowflake-connector-python-1.6.11
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

How do i enforce to use a single python path to be used ? installing modules via pip also should point to a one particular python path and the same has to be used. Since, many available and it's conflicting me.

```
 Could you please help me better solution to deal with conflict of pythons on mac ?
```

It has become huge problem to deal with python paths on mac. Any help to understand the concepts also welcome.

Comment: If you have package conflicts, use a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). It will handle the `PYTHONPATH` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtualenv (Virtual Environments) is created for this reason. 
Best way is to use pipenv = pip + venv : https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It will setup an environment for you project so it does not conflict with other projects

Comment: Did it perfectly. installed modules the way piping wanted, pipenv requests, pipenv install snowflake-connector-python,pipenv pyOpenSSL But still i could see the issue posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024670/importerror-cannot-import-name-dump-publickey/53054960#53054960

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name dump_publickey

Comment: can you please help me ?